# Getting select values from a JSON object

Tags: json

I want to return the followers_count of a twitter user.  When I do a get request to the api the JSON I am returned is:

EDIT: There is multiple parts to the response the part I want to extract data from starts like:

```
body:'[{"id":842072275,"id_str":"842072275","name":"BreaK","screen_name":"BreaK_71","location":"England","description":"Full Time Streamer from the UK","url":"http:\\/\\/t.co\\/YZTfi5U7AE","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\\/\\/t.co\\/YZTfi5U7AE","expanded_url":"http:\\/\\/www.twitch.tv\\/break71","display_url":"twitch.tv\\/break71","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":4159,"friends_count":211,"listed_count":43,"created_at":"Sun Sep 23 17:13:19 +0000 2012","favourites_count":4262,"utc_offset":7200,"time_zone":"Amsterdam","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":9763,"lang":"en","status":{"created_at":"Fri Apr 08 17:46:52 +0000 2016","id":718495339188195328,"id_str":"718495339188195328","text":"Hey I\'m live with some @BattleRoyaleMod talking hype about the Tournament tomorrow and messing around. Lets gooo! https:\\/\\/t.co\\/4V9CHaTcIK","entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"BattleRoyaleMod","name":"PLAYERUNKNOWN","id":1880574811,"id_str":"1880574811","indices":[23,39]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/t.co\\/4V9CHaTcIK","expanded_url":"http:\\/\\/twitch.tv\\/break71","display_url":"twitch.tv\\/break71","indices":[114,137]}]},"truncated":false,"source":"\\u003ca href=\\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\"\\u003eTwitter Web Client\\u003c\\/a\\u003e","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":3,"favorite_count":5,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"},"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"1A1B1F","profile_background_image_url":"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/642608935812374528\\/7t7IqgIJ.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/642608935812374528\\/7t7IqgIJ.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/693388490642423808\\/vdfXvyl4_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/693388490642423808\\/vdfXvyl4_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_banners\\/842072275\\/1410269304","profile_link_color":"ED7811","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"F6FFD1","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":true,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false}]' }
```

How do I extract only the followers_count key value pair.  As this is the only part I need.  I may choose others after but this is the main part. 
I have tried doing something like:

```
console.log(response.body['followers_count']);
```

But that doesnt work.

Comment: Did you parse json? Where is response defined?

Comment: `var params = {screen_name: 'twitter'};
  client.get('users/lookup', params,  function(error, tweets, response){
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }else{
  console.log("hello");
  console.log();  
var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(responseObject);
  // Raw response object.
}
});`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is:

```
var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(responseObject[0].followers_count)
```

Mind you, the string you pasted above as response is not a valid JSON but I assume it's an errore in copy / paste. You can use an [online json validator](http://jsonlint.com/) to test it.

Comment: Ye I tried putting in a JSON validator its not correct however that is the what is returned by the twitter API.  When i try your code above I get undefined:1 [object object] Unexpected token o.   Im not sure why twitter is returning invalid json.  I copied and pasted the reponse from my command line which may be why?

Comment: I think its trying to parse an object and the [ is throwing it off ?

Comment: As long as the response is not valid JSON, it will never work. Now, I doubt that Twitter API really returns invalid JSON, so I guess it's not properly escaped / handled in your code. Finding what's wrong it's beyond my capability, I just answered your original question :-)

Comment: Yeah apologies, I missed part of the JSON it actually has different parts.  The part that holds the data is contained within the body.

Answer (score 0):

`response[0].followers_count;` this will work.